optimum amount of pH buffer for an experiment
If trying to do an experiment involving the effect of pH on enzyme activity, is there any sort of guide as to how much pH buffer to add?

There's no way to answer this - it entirely depends on your assay and how you want to go about it. Further details needed.

@user338907 Can you please make your comments into a full answer? Thanks.
